# OpenWebStart + IcedTea-Web: JavaScript launch button

Tags: javascript, java, java-web-start, icedtea-web, openwebstart

With [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/) (Java SE 11), what JavaScript script should we use [to create the launch button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html)?

With Java SE 8 I used:

```
  <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
  [...]
  <script>
      var url = "ConfigureButtonsSample.jnlp";
      deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '11');
  </script>
```

Is this still the recommended script for Java SE 11/ OpenWebStart? Or is there a replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we do not have such replacement for OpenWebStart. At the moment we do not plan to invest in this area.